# Using pysed in script

Tags: python, sed

I can run successfully on command line but having problems in python script. It complains of the second double quote.

```
pysed -r "192.168.33.10" "$NEW_IP" FILE --write
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I run this inside a script?

Comment: pysed is meant to be executed from a shell. It is written in Python but not meant to be used from inside of Python.

Comment: @hek2mgl that hasn't always been the case - see docs for pysed 0.2.3 for example - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysed/0.2.3

Answer (score 1):

It's true that the module has no documentation for using it as a library.  But digging around the source, you can figure out how to use it.

For example:

```
import shlex
from pysed import main as pysedmain

pattern = '192.168.33.10'
new_ip = '192.168.0.1'
filename = '/path/to/my/file.txt'

command_line_args = '-r "{pattern}" "{replacement}" {filename}'.format(pattern=pattern, replacement=new_ip, filename=filename)
args = shlex.split(command_line_args)
isWrite = True

with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        data = f.read()
        pysedmain.executeArguments(args, data, filename, isWrite)
```

Comment: And what is the benefit of that? Replacing a string in a file is simple using plain python code.

Comment: @hek2mgl because if you're migrating an existing script with complex sed rexes, the interface is convenient and safe