# Replacing characters/delimiters (double comma) in CSV file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that produce an empty column every other column due to a `,,` delimiter. I"m trying to remove these empty columns, but I can't figure out how to loop thru the rows and replace the `,,` with `,`.

Any help looping thru the lines and replacing the delimiters would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Example data:

```
Year,,2005-12,,2006-12,,2007-12,,2008-12,,2009-12,,2010-12,,2011-12,,2012-12,,2013-12,,2014-12,,TTM
Data1,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `csv` module:

```
import csv

input = open('in.csv', 'rb')
output = open('out.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)

for read in csv.reader(input):
    writer.writerow([x for x in read if x]) #Removes empty fields and writes into new file

input.close()
output.close()
```

Although if the input csv file is pretty large then I don't think this would be an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the command line with pysed:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysed

```
(stackoverflow)macbook:stackoverflow joeyoung$ pip install pysed
(stackoverflow)macbook:stackoverflow joeyoung$ cat file.csv 
Year,,2005-12,,2006-12,,2007-12,,2008-12,,2009-12,,2010-12,,2011-12,,2012-12,,2013-12,,2014-12,,TTM
Data1,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00,,100.00
(stackoverflow)macbook:stackoverflow joeyoung$ pysed -r ",," "," file.csv --write
(stackoverflow)macbook:stackoverflow joeyoung$ cat file.csv 
Year,2005-12,2006-12,2007-12,2008-12,2009-12,2010-12,2011-12,2012-12,2013-12,2014-12,TTM
Data1,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00,100.00
```

Comment: Can you run pysed inside a script instead of at the command line?

Comment: Yes, but not as easily as a one-liner.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33899723/2744166

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it via python then use the replace method.

```
>>> s = 'year,,2015-12,,2006-12'
>>> print(s)
year,,2015-12,,2006-1
>>> new_s = s.replace(",,",",")
>>> print(new_s)
year,2015-12,2006-12
```